# Using variable-width font in Putty

Tags: windows, fonts, terminal, putty, variable-width

[VT100-style terminal handling](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#4.7.2) deals with fixed-width fonts.

Is it possible to use variable-width font like Comic Sans MS in Putty on Windows? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

No. PuTTY fundamentally assumes evenly sized character cells in a regular grid and hence requires a fixed-width font. (Well, actually dual-width, because double-width characters are needed for East Asian languages.)

I'm not aware of a terminal that does allow proportional fonts. Perhaps there is one out there, but of course terminal applications also assume a regular grid of character cells, so I'm not sure how useful it would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can by changing the following registry value:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\Default%20Settings\Font
```